# ng-repeat issue in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting below error. Anyone suggest me how to solve this error message.

> BlockquoteDuplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: col in tableData3 | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse, Duplicate key: object:49, Duplicate value: {"programName":"2015 Commercial Natural Gas Kitchen Equipment Rebates","incentiveType":"Efficiency","incentiveProgram":"Bussiness and Institution","incentiveCategory":"Appliances","keyword":"Ovens\nFryers\nGriddles\nSteamers\nSpray Valves","fuelSource":"Natural Gas","incentiveDetail":"Natural Gas Kitchen Equipment Rebates","eligibility":"Contact your energy efficiency Program Administrator to discuss terms and eligibility. Purchase and installation must be within 1/1/2015-12/31/2015.","participatingUtility":"Berkshire Gas,\nCape Light Compact,\nColumbia Gas of Massachusetts,\nNational Grid,\nNew England Gas,\nEversource,\nUnitil.","amount":"High-Efficiency Conveyor Oven: $1000 High-Efficiency Rack Oven: $1000 Energy Star Fryer: $1000 Energy Star Convection Oven: $1000 Energy Star Steamer: $1000 Energy Star Griddle: $500 High Efficiency Pre-Rinse Spray Valves: $50","contact":"http://www.masssave.com/~/media/Files/Business/Applicatio...) 628-8413"}

Comment: Hi!!! welcome to StackOverflow When you are trying to aks any question is pretty usefull that you give us diferente code that would help us to give you a solution.

Comment: The error is telling you how to fix it! At least enough that you can get past that issue and see what it produces

Answer (score 1):

from the error message - I am guessing you have a duplicate item in your collection and ng-repeat needs a collection of unique items. Check your collection or array.